# Could I hook up 2 external monitors to my Vaio vpccw2s1e?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, sony-vaio

I have a [VAIO vpccw2s1e](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Sony-Vaio-VPC-CW2S1E-L-Notebook.27414.0.html) and I am wondering if it is possible to have 2 external monitors. 
There is an HDMI and a VGA port, but when I plug the VGA cable there is not enough room for the HDMI one (ports too close together).

Are there any solutions for that? (I don't care if my laptop monitor will work as long as I have the 2 external ones..)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply cut the VGA table ending plastic and used a tool to bend the metal a bit , now it fits, I can use 2 external monitors if I disable the laptop one, works like a charm. You don't need the screws anyway for the laptop.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A smaller form factor VGA cable may work in your case.

If you can borrow one or test one at a store that may solve your problem.

Additionally, you can also a try a right angle HDMI cable so it doesn't take up all the space.

A quick Amazon.com search will help you find the above products.

Comment: I couldn't find the small vga you are talking about.. the HDMI is rather small already, most of the space is because of the VGA's screwfixes

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Profile-Resolution-Monitor-Cable/dp/B000G6XY42/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1365611533&sr=1-1&keywords=low+profile+vga+cable

Comment: aha, thanks, I don't think it changes much though, the problematic part is the ending.. see : http://img1.lesnumeriques.com/produits/16/7468/Sony_Vaio_VPCCW1S1E_LeftSide.jpg